# Unparseable date: "2017-11-24T05:27:00.000z" at offset 23

Tags: react-native

I am passing date in "2017-11-24T05:27:00.000Z" this format to `addToCalendar`. On iOS it works fine, but android gives above error.

```js
var start_date = "2017-11-24T05:27:00.000Z";
var end_date = "2017-11-27T05:27:00.000Z"

const eventConfig = {title:'Event name', location:'Satara', notes:'Added event', startDate: start_date, endDate: end_date};

addCalendarEvent(eventConfig) {
  AddCalendarEvent.presentNewCalendarEventDialog(eventConfig)
    .then(eventId => {
      // handle success (receives event id) or dismissing the modal (receives false)
      if (eventId) {
        alert('Event Created');
      } else {
        console.warn('dismissed');
      }
    })
    .catch((error: string) => {
      // handle error such as when user rejected permissions
      console.warn(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using the module [`react-native-add-calendar-event`](https://github.com/vonovak/react-native-add-calendar-event).
Check which version you're using as I can see this [issue](https://github.com/vonovak/react-native-add-calendar-event/issues/9) has been [fixed](https://github.com/vonovak/react-native-add-calendar-event/releases/tag/v0.3.0) recently.

Comment: I updated react-native-add-calendar-event to 0.3 and it is working fine. Thank you so much